# remove special character with directive not work angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i want transform text in uppercase and remove special character of input text using directive.

the directive is this:

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, Output, Input, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[uppercase]',
    host: {
        '[value]': 'uppercase',
        '(input)': 'format($event.target.value)'
    }
})

export class UppercaseDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input() uppercase: string;
    @Output() uppercaseChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.uppercase = this.uppercase || '';
        this.format(this.uppercase);
    }

      format(value) {
    let regNumber = /^\d+$/;
    if (!value || regNumber.test(value)) return
    let valueValido = value.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');
        valueValido = valueValido.toUpperCase();
        this.uppercaseChange.next(valueValido);
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
    console.log(valueValido)
}
    }

}
```

the input continue show special caracter, but in log i can see the value, and it not have more special caracter.
i use '' to replace, and not work, but if i use any caracter or space to replace ex: ' ', it work, but i need replace with no value ''. How i can do it?

[image]

@Edit
the solution not work, the code:

```
   <div [ngSwitch]="input.controlType">
        <div class="ui-g-12" *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [class.esconder]="input.hidden"  >
                <label for="input.key">{{input.label | doisPontos}}</label><br>
      <input [formControlName]="input.key" [id]="input.key" [type]="input.type" [ngStyle]="{'width':input.width}"
       pInputText [(uppercase)]="form.controls[input.key].value" [class.ui-state-error]="form.controls[input.key].touched && form.controls[input.key].invalid "
       [value]="form.controls[input.key].value | removeEspecialCaractere"  >
          </div>
```

the pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'removeEspecialCaractere'
    })
    export class removeEspecialCaracterePipe implements PipeTransform {  
        transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
          return value === undefined ? '' : value.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '').toUpperCase();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Text transform you have to use pipe

Comment: i create a pipe with this code and this problem continue..

Comment: try this line `this.uppercaseChange.emit(valueValido);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Text Transform use Pipe. place the pipe transform where you want to remove special character

**html**

```
 {{ p | transform}}
```

**transform.pipe.ts**

```
 transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return value === undefined ? '' : value.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '').toUpperCase();
  }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wp12pu

Comment: not work... pipe tag im put in input form like this:  [value]="form.controls[input.key].value | removeEspecialCaractere" 
its correct?

Comment: <input type="text" [value]="p | transform"> yes i have updated the stackblitz check